# Why can't the F# compiler fully inline function arguments of a higher order function?

Tags: performance, f#

One of the things I love about F# is a real `inline` keyword. However, while it allows to write first order functions that perform the same as pasted code blocks, things aren't so rosy for higher order functions. Consider

```
let inline add i = i+1
let inline check i = if (add i) = 0 then printfn ""    
let inline iter runs f = for i = 0 to runs-1 do f i
let runs = 100000000
time(fun()->iter runs check) 1
time(fun()->for i = 0 to runs-1 do check i) 1
```

The results are `244 ms` for `iter` and `61 ms` for manual checks. Let's delve into ILSpy. The relevant function called for the direct call is:

```
internal static void func@22-12(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 == 0)
        {
            Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, System.IO.TextWriter, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit> format = new Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, System.IO.TextWriter, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>("");
            Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatLineToTextWriter<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>(System.Console.Out, format);
        }
    }
}
```

With `add` inlined. The relevant function for `iter` is

```
internal static void func@22-11(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        Tests.FunctionInlining.f@315-5(i);
    }
}
internal static void f@315-5(int i)
{
    if (i + 1 == 0)
    {
        Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, System.IO.TextWriter, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit> format = new Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, System.IO.TextWriter, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>("");
        Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatLineToTextWriter<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>(System.Console.Out, format);
        return;
    }
}
```

And we can see the performance penalty comes from one extra level of indirection. As the performance test shows, this indirection is also not removed by the JIT compiler. Is there a reason for why the higher order functions cannot be fully inlined? This is a pain when writing a computational kernel.

My time combinator (though not really relevant here) is

```
let inline time func n =
    func() |> ignore
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    let stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    for i = 0 to n-1 do func() |> ignore
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "Took %A ms" stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Please confirm that you ran this program in Release mode without debugger attached. Apart from that the benchmark seems valid. You could improve it by increasing the work by a factor of 10 to rue out the influence of one-time costs.

Comment: @usr Yes, I ran it without debugger and compiled in Release mode. There can be no doubt the performance difference is real though because it can be deduced from the IL code (barring JIT optimisations).

Comment: @Arbil I've linked to this question on one of the F# Language Design UserVoice threads about inlining analysis: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6137978-better-inlining-analysis-and-heuristic-algorithms

Comment: here is another discussion about inline optimizations: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/162

Comment: @JackP. Thanks. As far as I understand the fslang proposal is more advanced -- it's about heuristic analysis of algorithms. Here there's no algorithmic subtlety -- if I mark both the second order function and its first order argument function as inline, I want the result of application be inlined 'all the way down'. That is an unequivocal instruction for the compiler. I'll mention this at fslang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to be clear, the F# compiler is inlining every definition that you've marked as `inline`.  It's just that the current behavior of inlining isn't very useful when using an inlined function as a higher-order argument.  `check` can only be inlined when given an argument, and so `iter runs check` is treated as `iter runs (fun i -> check i)`.  Then `check` gets inlined, resulting in the equivalent of

```
iter runs (fun i -> if (add i) = 0 then printfn "")
```

(as you can see in the IL, there is no call to `check` in the generated IL, but there is a call to the synthetic `f@315-5` body for this lambda, which is equivalent).  `iter` gets inlined, too.

Having said that, I agree that the current behavior isn't as useful as it could be - the compiler could also inline the body of the lambda into the call site, which would be safe and improve performance.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is true that the problem is not a non-inlined `check` but a non-inlined function derived from `check`. This however as far as I can tell is not peculiar to my example but happens for all higher order function calls. Therefore performance-wise it is identical to the function argument not being inlined. Why don't we (those interested in high-performance/scientific/game development with F#) push for some of these issues to be fixed? No. 1 is struct tuples, this is no. 2. Currently on fslang there are very few up-voted performance-related proposals.

Comment: I would be happy to go on a performance upvoting spree with you.  High level languages are amazing but the attitude of "performance doesn't matter" leads to a anti-virtuous cycle to the point that it does matter.